# No se me muestra una imagen en mi pagina

Tags: php, html, imagen, error404

no se me muestra una imagen correctamente en mi pagina, estoy creando un login y pues necesito ponerla, y simplemente no se muestra abajo adjuntaré todas las imagenes necesarias
[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.)

[image: esta es la ruta]com/zaK2e.jpg

[image: este es el codigo]

[image: ahí se ve que está la carpeta imagenes donde esta la imagen]

[image: así se me ve]

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio, así obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). En el caso del código, siempre es mejor colocar el texto en lugar de una imagen

Comment: Quita el `./` del inicio de la ruta de tu imagen. Elimina las cookies del navegador e intenta abrir el link directamente desde la pestaña del navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Puede parecer algo obvio pero, por que no intentas copiar toda la ruta de la direccion del archivo en la hoja de estilos haber si te resulta.

Comment: No parece ser la respuesta al problema.